# stop countdown refresh if browser refresh clicked

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying a countdown timer for 120 seconds, I have hard coded the value and countdown and its

```js
var timeleft = 120;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Token expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

working properly, the problem is if I hit browser refresh button the countdown starts again, how can I stop that. I got to know that i have to use local storage or session storage how can I achieve this? any other way to do so. below is my sample code

```
var timeleft = 120;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Token expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You can use the localStorage and save the time on which the countdown starts. Then, whenever the page is loaded you can check if there is a time in the localStorage and calculate the remaining time for the countdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try using localStorage

```
var timeleft = localStorage.getItem("key") ? localStorage.getItem("key") : 120;

var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  localStorage.setItem("key", timeleft);
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Token expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/twentyTwo/9v3z740d/12/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timeleft = localStorage.getItem("myTime")? localStorage.getItem("myTime"):120;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  timeleft -= 1;
  localStorage.setItem("myTime",timeleft);
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Token expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

It will start from previous value even refresh takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand your question is that you countdown to a particular time and day. SO you have to set a deadline, otherwise it will vanish in each refresh. So I hope this code will help you.

```
var deadline = new Date("May 8, 2019 15:37:25").getTime(); 
var x = setInterval(function() { 
   var now = new Date().getTime(); 
   var t = deadline - now; 
   var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
   var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60)); 
   var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); 
   var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000); 
   document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + "d "  
   + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "; 
    if (t < 0) { 
        clearInterval(x); 
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED"; 
    } 
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the countdown to maintain the count regardless of refresh, you can set the date once and compute the remaining time on refresh.

```js
var timeleft = 120;

var startTime = localStorage['startTime'];
if (startTime) {
    timeDiff = Math.floor((Date.now() - startTime)/1000);
    timeleft -= timeDiff;
} else {
    localStorage['startTime'] = Date.now();
}

var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
  timeleft -= 1;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Token expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

If you want the countdown to be based on the continuity of seconds on each refresh, storing in localStorage on each interval would be the way to go.